# Firefox: How to "bookmark" page contents (for long articles to be able to easily navigate through where one has ended reading for example)

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, bookmarks

This is difficult to search for because the term "bookmark" is widely used as a bookmark for the whole page.

The functionality that I'm looking for is, like, a "traditional bookmark" inside a page.

I'm looking for a way that would allow me to set a bookmark in any place of text of a page and would remember that bookmark over computer shutdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Firefox extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/anchorme/ seems to work for some.